# Nimbers for Kayles

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I have a problem with calculating the nimbers for this game. 
I know that for Kayles the following is true:
\begin{array}{c|c}
\hline
 Hight & Nimber \\ \hline
 12 & ^*4 \\ \hline
 11 & ^*6 \\ \hline
 10 & ^*2 \\ \hline
 9 & ^*4 \\ \hline
 8 & ^*1 \\ \hline
 7 & ^*2 \\ \hline
 6 & ^*3 \\ \hline
 5 & ^*4 \\ \hline
 4 & ^*1 \\ \hline
 3 & ^*3 \\ \hline
 2 & ^*2 \\ \hline
 1 & ^*1 \\ \hline
 0 & ^*0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

My attempt to get to these numbers:

n(0) = mex{} = 0

n(1) = mex{0} = 1

n(2) = mex{0, 1} = 2

However,

n(3) = mex{1, 2} = 0

which is obviously the wrong result.

What I am trying to figure out is how to calculate those nimber values. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From a position with 3 pins in a single row a player also has the option to bowl out the pin in the middle, leaving two isolated rows with one pin in each. That position has the NIM-sum of $1$ and $1$, i.e $0$ as its Sprague-Grundy value. Therefore $n(3)=mex\{0,1,2\}=3.$ I suspect your other difficulties with this table are similar.

Comment: I guess, that might very well be my mistake. I completely forgot that Kayles is one of those games that allow splitting rows in multiple parts.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

A third option for the game of length $3$, in addition to leaving a game of length $1$ or a game of length $2$, is to leave two games of length $1$, with value $1\oplus1=0$, so $n(3)=\mathrm{mex}\{0,1,2\}=3$.